Getting ‘Failed to perform cmdlineoperation’ when installing jmeter plugin in GitHub workflow file
I’m trying to install JMeter plugins in GitHub actions workflow file and running below command to do that -
Command - java -jar cmdrunner-2.2.1.jar --tool org.jmeterplugins.repository.PluginManagerCMD install-all-except jpgc-hadoop,jpgc-oauth,ulp-jmeter-autocorrelator-plugin,ulp-jmeter-videostreaming-plugin,ulp-jmeter-gwt-plugin,tilln-iso8583

I’m getting below error -
ERROR: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to perform cmdline operation: Read timed out
** Problem's technical details go below ***
Home directory was detected as: /usr/local/apache-jmeter-5.0/lib
Error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to perform cmdline operation: Read timed out
at org.jmeterplugins.repository.PluginManagerCMD.processParams(PluginManagerCMD.java:102)
at kg.apc.cmdtools.PluginsCMD.processParams(PluginsCMD.java:62)
at kg.apc.cmdtools.PluginsCMD.processParams(PluginsCMD.java:21)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:569)
at kg.apc.cmd.UniversalRunner.main(UniversalRunner.java:117)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedRead(NioSocketImpl.java:288)
... 7 more

How to solve this error ?

JMeter Plugins Manager tries to connect with the plugins repository at https://jmeter-plugins.org/repo
If connection cannot be established - you won't be able to use Plugins Manager.
Make sure that your Github Actions runner machine can access Internet in general and https://jmeter-plugins.org in particular.
You might also try to increase the timeout by by manipulating jpgc.repo.timeout JMeter Property
